# Left justified caption and centered table problem

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

As I wrote in the heading, have the following problem:
[image]

I want this table to be centred in the undermentioned text, and the caption above the table should start with the left margin (flushed left), not with the space as you can see. This is the written code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\small
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=justified}
\caption[Stopień spęcznienia]{Dane przedstawiające stopień spęcznienia każdego rodzaju membran. Stopień spęcznienia został obliczony na podstawie wzoru (\ref{eqn:specznienie})}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-7}
& ChTPP1 & ChTPP2 & ChTPP3 & ChTPP1HA & ChTPP2HA & ChTPP3HA\\  \cline{1-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{2.4cm}|}{\centering Stopień spęcznienia (\%)} & 1244.24 & 1132.06 & 787.62 & 2588.73 & 1650.25 & 1363.64\\
\cline{1-7}
\end{tabularx}
\label{table:specznienie}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Does it help if you set `\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}`?

Comment: Thank you! It helps with the caption, now it's flushed left, but the table is still not centered.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Please provide a MWE to work with the issue

Comment: @barnaba - The way you're using `tabularx` is wrong; your table is wider that your text width; see the answer from Zarko for the correct usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

If you use `tabularx` you sould use `X` column type or its modification (see MWE below). Since table width is equal to text width, it doesn't need be centered in the text. I anticipated, that you like to have equal width of cells with centering content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \small
\captionsetup{justification=justified}
    \caption[Stopień spęcznienia]{Dane przedstawiające stopień spęcznienia każdego rodzaju membran. Stopień spęcznienia został obliczony na podstawie wzoru (\ref{eqn:specznienie})}
\label{table:specznienie}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{C|}}
    \cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    & ChTPP1    & ChTPP2    & ChTPP3 & ChTPP1HA & ChTPP2HA  & ChTPP3HA\\  
    \cline{1-7}
Stopień spęcznienia (\%) 
    & 1244.24   & 1132.06   & 787.62 & 2588.73  & 1650.25   & 1363.64   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the case, that you like to have vertically centered cells content, than you should add topreamble

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
```

With this  the table looks as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably this should work:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h]
\small
\captionsetup{justification=justified}
\caption[Stopień spęcznienia]{Dane przedstawiające stopień spęcznienia każdego rodzaju membran. Stopień spęcznienia został obliczony na podstawie wzoru (\ref{eqn:specznienie})}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-7}
& ChTPP1 & ChTPP2 & ChTPP3 & ChTPP1HA & ChTPP2HA & ChTPP3HA\\  \cline{1-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{2.4cm}|}{\centering Stopień spęcznienia (\%)} & 1244.24 & 1132.06 & 787.62 & 2588.73 & 1650.25 & 1363.64\\
\cline{1-7}
\end{tabularx}
\label{table:specznienie}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: I have done what you wtore, but still the table isn't centered

Comment: Additionally, if i set `begin{flushright} ... end{flushright}` nothing is changed at all.