# Vertically centered cells issue and squeezing space after the table

Tags: tables

Including the picture:

[image]

To be honest, I've already seen that the cells **ChTPP1**, **CHTPP2** and so on, seem to be centered vertically. So that, it's not a problem anymore. However I can not find the solution why there is such a huge distance between the end of the table and the first line of the text below. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\captionsetup{font={small,stretch=1}}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=6pt}
%\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

\titlespacing*\section{0pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{6pt plus 3pt minus 3pt}
\titlespacing*\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 6pt minus 6pt}{6pt plus 3pt minus 3pt}
\titlespacing*\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 6pt minus 6pt}{6pt plus 3pt minus 3pt}
\titlespacing*\paragraph{0pt}{12pt plus 6pt minus 6pt}{6pt plus 3pt minus 3pt}

\setlength{\intextsep}{12pt plus 3pt minus 3pt}

\begin{center}
 \begin{table}[ht]
  \small
  \captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
  \caption[Stopień spęcznienia]{Dane przedstawiające stopień spęcznienia każdego rodzaju membran. Stopień spęcznienia został obliczony na podstawie wzoru    (\ref{eqn:specznienie})}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{C|}}
   \cline{2-7}
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
& ChTPP1 & ChTPP2 & ChTPP3 & ChTPP1HA & ChTPP2HA & ChTPP3HA\\  
   \cline{1-7} 
Stopień spęcznienia (\%) & 1244.24 & 1132.06 & 787.62 & 2588.73 & 1650.25 & 1363.64\\
   \hline
 \end{tabularx}
\label{table:specznienie}
\end{table}
\end{center}

Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text

\end document
```

Comment: You should not have `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` around the table, which does nothing except for adding some vertical space at the spot. Use `\centering` *inside* the `table` environment (although in this specific case you can even do without it).

Comment: I've found the solution. Had to remove `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}, now the break is proper. Does anyone know why it works?

Comment: The `table` adds a vertical spacing around tabulars, end `center` adds another one, but `\centering` just centres, without adding whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is follow on question to your question [left-justified-caption-and-centered-table-problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345506/left-justified-caption-and-centered-table-problem/345516#345516). And accepted answer already provide solution of your problem. To emphasize it, I only add dummy text before and after

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
    \begin{table}[h]
    \small
\captionsetup{justification=justified}
    \caption[Stopień spęcznienia]{Dane przedstawiające stopień spęcznienia każdego rodzaju membran. Stopień spęcznienia został obliczony na podstawie wzoru (\ref{eqn:specznienie})}
\label{table:specznienie}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{C|}}
    \cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    & ChTPP1    & ChTPP2    & ChTPP3 & ChTPP1HA & ChTPP2HA  & ChTPP3HA\\
    \cline{1-7}
Stopień spęcznienia (\%)
    & 1244.24   & 1132.06   & 787.62 & 2588.73  & 1650.25   & 1363.64   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

*Note:*
newer enclose float element inside `\begin{center}\begin{figure}...\end{{figure}\end{center}`! The right way is, as you already informed in comments above, use only `\begin{figure}\centering ... \end{figure}`.